# How to copy content from one space to other space in contenful?

Tags: contentful

I have created a new space in contentful. Now I want to copy all content model, content from old space to new created space to save my time.**Please assist me how I can do that?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Contentful CLI](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/tutorials/general/import-and-export/) for that. All the content can be exported to a JSON file which then can be imported into a new space.